# jQuery error when defining object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an Ajax form which calls a JavaScript function `OnFailure`. Here is the function that should show the error message in a div to the user:

```
function showError(ajaxContext) {
        var response = ajaxContext.responseText;
        response = $(response);
        var itemVersion = response.filter("div")[0].innerHTML.trim().toString();
        var error = response.filter("p")[0].outerHTML.toString();
        $("#" + itemVersion.replace(".", "") + "-UpdateStagesResults").empty();
        $(error).appendTo("#" + itemVersion.replace(".", "") + "-UpdateStagesResults");
    }
```

The code fails on the `response = $(response);`, the error being in the jQuery 1.9.1 file:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
    <p>You have not entered a valid date</p>
    <div  style="display:none;">V10.0</div>
    <div id="V10.0" class="error"></div>
```

It was working fine the last time I checked, but now it is erroring and I can't see why. Any help would be great!

Comment: What looks like `itemVersion` ???

Comment: `itemVersion` should just be `V10.0`, but the code fails before it gets to that point.

Comment: So which line throws error??? EDIT: sorry, didn't see you have already post it

Comment: `response = $(response);`

Comment: so try even you didn't post what is value of response: `response = $($.trim(response));` EDIT: still sorry, looks like response value already posted, i need more coffee, my bad. But: `<div id="V10.0" class="error"></div` should be: `<div id="V10.0" class="error"></div>` and btw, ID with dot is not valid

Comment: That was a typo sorry. But if I replace `response = $(response);` with `response = $($.trim(response));` it works. If you put this as an answer I will mark it correct but if you can explain why this works that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always trim string if coming from server and wrapped in jQuery object. Because server can returns any invisible character(s) at start or end of returned string, depending how you return response or file encoding (BOM?):

```
response = $($.trim(response));
```